# How to limit the consuming rate from a topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

Has anyone else solved the following problem?
I have **SNS topic**  filled with events from **S3** and there is **Lambda function** which is subscribed on this topic and when thousand of events are put to this topic, lambda function is throttled because of exceeding the limit of concurrency.
 I don't want to request a limit increase for concurrent executions but I would decrease concurrent consuming from the topic, but I didn't find information how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple of options regarding SNS:

1) **SNS Maximum Receive Rate**

Set the [SNS Maximum Receive Rate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/DeliveryPolicies.html#delivery-policy-maximum-receive-rate). This will throttle the SNS messages sent to a subscriber, but may not be a great option if you have so many messages that  they will be discarded before they can be processed. From the documentation:

> You can set the maximum number of messages per second that Amazon SNS
>   sends to a subscribed endpoint by setting the Maximum receive rate
>   setting. Amazon SNS holds messages that are awaiting delivery for up
>   to an hour. Messages held for more than an hour are discarded.

If you're only getting thousands of events at a time, setting the Maximum Receive Rate to Lambda's [default concurrent execution limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of '100' might be worth a try.

As @kndrk notes, this throttling is currently only available for HTTP/HTTPS subscribers to the SNS topic. To work around this, you can [expose your lambda function via AWS API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) and subscribe that endpoint to the SNS topic, rather than the lambda function directly.

2) **Process from SQS**

[Subscribe an SQS queue to the SNS topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html) and process messages from the queue, rather than directly from the sns topic. A single invokation of SQS [ReceiveMessage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) can only handle 10 messages at a time, so that may be easier for you to throttle.

---

It is also worth noting that you can publish [S3 Events directly to AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I tried the solution when lambda was triggering by S3 but the same problem has occurred, therefore I decided to try combination S3->sns->lambda. I'm going to try your first option, it may be suitable for me.

**P.S.** I want to process events from S3 immediately because in most cases the load is not so high, but if I understood correctly, lambda cannot be triggered by events from SQS. Only way it is to schedule executing of lambda function for consuming from SQS

Comment: That's correct -- for SQS you would essentially be polling SQS RecieveMessage from lambda on a schedule instead of plugging it into a specific trigger. It sounds like from your comment that SNS Maximum Receive Rate would be a nice fit for your use case. Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Unfortunately this only applies to HTTP(s) endpoints. Lambda subscribers aren't throttled at all.

Comment: Thanks @knrdk! Wasn't following that initially but I re-read and that's a great point! Think we can get around that with an API Gateway endpoint, I've updated answer with a workaround.

Comment: Yup, it works for API Gateway endpoints, so that's what we ended up doing.

Comment: Please note throttle is available for SNS [up to 3 times](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns)

Comment: Regarding `SNS Maximum Receive Rate`, the quote doesn't exist anymore in the document. Does it mean that the message will stay in the SNS until it's delivered?

Comment: @AnthonyNeace Have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900337/what-happens-to-sns-self-throttled-messages-which-are-not-delivered-for-a-long).