# What happens to SNS' self throttled messages which are not delivered for a long time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, throttling

Say that I have a SNS which I am self throttling using the attribute `maxReceivesPerSecond`. Let's say we have a very high production rate, but due to the throttling, the consumption is very slow. This can lead to some messages being in the SNS for a long time.

I saw this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454037/5345646), where it's mentioned that such messages will be deleted after 1 hour. But the quote doesn't exist in the documentation anymore.

So what is the current policy of deletion of un-delivered messages in a SNS now?

Comment: I also got confused now. Maybe better to delete the answer and let someone else clarify this.

Comment: @Marcin Have started a bounty on this question. We might get the answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon SNS now allows you to set a TTL (Time to Live) value of up to two weeks for each message. Messages that remain undelivered for the given period of time (expressed as a number of seconds since the message was published) will expire and will not be delivered.

You should refer to this link for more details:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sns-ttl-control/

Comment: So you will award the bounty too?

Comment: This applies only to mobile push notifications. What about any other sns use-case?

Comment: Which use-case are you looking for?

Comment: What about anything else? SNS with lambda, SQS, HTTP subscriptions?

Comment: You can use SQS as well. You can use SNS to send the message to SQS and then SQS sends the message. SQS has a better throttling than SNS. You can also use Lambda to trigger SNS.

Comment: @Mooncrater : Are you going to award the bounty?