# Per client throttling for SNS

Tags: amazon-sns, throttling, rate-limiting

Let's say we have 3 message producers, which send messages to SNS

I want to have client specific throttling for the SNS. I see "SNS Maximum Receive Rate", [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454037/5345646), but I think that is a general rule for *every* client.

Is there a way to do client specific throttling in SNS? If not, what are some good alternatives?

I understand that API gateway is an option - But I want to explore the SNS route first, and if that doesn't work out, will look into other options.

Answer (score 0):

Did a deep dive into this. Found that the `maxReceivesPerSecond` is per subscription, as mentioned inside the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html) :

> The maximum number of deliveries per second, per subscription.

So we can use different `maxReceivesPerSecond` values.

Also, I see that we can have different DLQs (under "Redrive Policy") for different subscriptions. This means that if SNS is not able send some message, because of throttling, then those messages can go to the client's DLQ.